# Cron job: if/else conditions does not work as expected, if shell script is run from Cron job

Tags: shell, solaris, cron, sh

I wrote the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

MAIL=/usr/mail/${LOGNAME:?}

. /installations/etl_scripts/etl_job.properties 

JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH=$JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH
export JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH

JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME=$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
export JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME

JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME

CATALINA_HOME=$CATALINA_HOME
export CATALINA_HOME

PENTAHO_HOME=$PENTAHO_HOME
export PENTAHO_HOME

PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=$PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
export PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME

ETL_JOB_HOME=$ETL_JOB_HOME
export ETL_JOB_HOME

ETL_SCRIPTS_HOME=$ETL_SCRIPTS_HOME
export ETL_SCRIPTS_HOME

PATH=$PATH
export PATH

# Virre ETL transformation job execution
echo $ETL_JOB_ENABLED >> /tmp/templog.log
date +"%D %r `echo Scheduled Pentaho ETL job is starting...`" >> $JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
if [ $ETL_JOB_ENABLED = 'Yes' ]; then
    sh $PENTAHO_HOME/kitchen.sh -file $ETL_JOB_HOME/sync_job.kjb >> $JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
else
    echo "Pentaho ETL job is dissabled. Please enable it in etl_job.properties by setting ETL_JOB_ENABLED property to yes" >> $JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
fi
date +"%D %r `echo Completed`" >> $JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------- >> $JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
```

When I run it from console, if/else statements work as expected. But when it was ran from scheduled Cron job, it hangs somewhere in or before if statement: It successfully writes message before if statement to log file and after that nothing happens.

Any solutions how to resolve this?

Comment: What's in `/tmp/templog.log` when you run it via cron?  Also, what is the content of `$JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME` after a cron run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove extension for kitchen.sh file and also add full path to sh :

```
/bin/sh $PENTAHO_HOME/kitchen -file $ETL_JOB_HOME/sync_job.kjb >> $JOB_LOG_FILE_PATH/$JOB_LOG_FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks. Working if full path to .sh is set (/bin/sh ..)